# Lubuntu 15.04 & Windows 10: expanding partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, lubuntu, hard-drive

Lubuntu view:

[image]

Windows view:

[image]

I want to expand my current Lubuntu partition to use up all the free space left. However, Lubuntu doesn't differ between the real Windows partition and free space. Any safe solution?

I tried `gparted` as suggested in an answer, but have the same issue:

[image]

**UPDATE:** finally shut down Windows. Now, instead of exclamation mark symbol, there is a symbol of lock near the Windows partition: [image]

**UPDATE 2:**

`Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support:  ntfsprogs / ntfs-3g`

I can mount and unmount the partition as you instructed me without problems, though.

[image]

Final solution: reinstalled lubuntu with different settings. I could have tried to **move** the partition and then resize it, but that would have taken much more time than just reinstalling the whole OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your Windows system was hibernated and not actually shut down. That causes issues for Linux's ntfs3g driver. So, you need to boot back into Windows and shut it down cleanly.

In their infinite wisdom, the Microsoft developers decided to make it hard for users to shut down their machines. According to [this site](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2012202/how-to-shut-down-windows-8.html), you need to:

> 1. Mouse over the little gadget in the lower right corner of the screen. (You can also move your mouse cursor to the upper left corner;
>      same result. Or, you can press Windows-C on your keyboard.)
> 2. In the slide-out menu (known as the Charms Bar) that appears, click Settings.
> 3. Click the Power button, and then click your desired action: Sleep, Shut down, or Update and restart.

That's for Windows 8 though. [This site](http://techdows.com/2014/10/how-to-shutdown-or-restart-windows-10-from-the-start-menu.html) seems to suggest it is "easier"  on Windows 10:

> 1. Click on start button to pen the Start Menu
> 2. On top of it, click on ‘Power Options’ button next to your name (check the screenshot below) and click on ‘Shut down’ or ‘Restart’,
>      (Sleep option is also available, which you can use it, if you want).

Anyway, assuming Windows actually allows you to shut down your machine, you can now reboot into Linux where `gparted` should be able to correctly read and resize your drive. It should look something like this:

[image: screenshot of gparted showing free space on an NTFS drive]

While I have actually used `gparted` to resize NTFS partitions several times and have never had a problem, as always, **you should backup your data first**.

Comment: Installed gparted, no change.

Comment: @AlexWolf what do you mean "no change"? Did you run `sudo gparted`? Did that open a window like the one I show above with your disk drive? Was the empty space not listed? If so, please take a screenshot and add it to your question.

Comment: I added the screenshot.

Comment: Need more reputation to post more than two links.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I did what you said and things changed a little bit, but not enough to solve the issue. Could you take a look at my updated `GParted` view?

Comment: @AlexWolf that's because you've mounted it. Run `sudo umount /tmp/foo` and try again.

Comment: Did it. New error...